# Parse Querying Limit

Tags: parse-platform

If I have a PFQuery that will search through every user but I limit the results to 3 users, will that query search through every user and then give me 3 users? Or will the query pause/stop once 3 people have been found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will stop searching once it finds what you set as your [PFQuery's `.limit`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(py)limit).

And if you want to have pages of three users, you can use the [`.skip` property](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(py)skip), e.g. `.skip = pageNumber * 3`.